# Extract and return capital words from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) like this:

```
weather  day
rainy    Friday
Hot      saturday
cold     Sunday
```

how to extract the words starting with a capital letter on the day column and return them into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.findall`, then `explode`, `dropna` then call `to_list`:

```py
>>> df['day'].str.findall('^[A-Z].*').explode().dropna().to_list()
['Friday', 'Sunday']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```py
dataf.loc[lambda d: d["day"].str.istitle(), "day"].tolist()
```

This avoids loops. Basically, we select rows were we have a title. We could also do `d["day"].str[0].isupper()`, and then cast a day Series to a list.

Complete code:

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.DataFrame({"weather":  "rainy Hot cold".split(),
"day": "Friday saturday Sunday".split()})

results = dataf.loc[lambda d: d["day"].str.istitle(), "day"].tolist()
print(results)
# ['Friday', 'Sunday']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
l = df['day'][df['day'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
l = [i for i in l if i[0].isupper()]
```

And now:

```
print(l)
```

Gives:

```
['Friday', 'Sunday']
```

Comment: thank you. I edit my question. Can the list comprehension get adjusted only for the capital words on the day column?

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @giovanni Edited my answer, should work now! Please accept and upvote if it does

Comment: This is computationally expensive as it’s not vectorised. ;).